# Multi-currency wallet api

Tags: litecoin, api, currencies, dogecoin, digitalcoin

I need a api or an application that can generate and handle (send/receive and so on...) multi currency wallet.
For an example: It can generate dogecoin address, bitcoin address, litecoin address, peercoin address and so on... and handle them. Like send/receive/check balance.

Comment: Please read why you shouldn't thank users for reading your question (and reverting edits towards that direction): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: The RPC API is identical for almost every client...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few API providers that do multi-currency / wallet integration. The first that comes to mind is https://www.block.io/ they support LiteCoin/DogeCoin and Bitcoin. There may be others that have even wider digital currency support.

The way that most people do this is by running separate instances for each client blockchain and then using the RPC interface. There are similarities between most of the coins that forked Bitcoin. So although more resource intensive you could run each client you were interested in and use the native interface to communicate with them individually.

Comment: Hmm... I dont really want to run all client program for each currency becuase to generate a address...

Comment: Its easier to use an external API, mostly because you don't have to manage the underlying infrastructure. But the address generation is the same, you run the getnewaddress rpc call on the node for the type of address you want.

Answer (score 3):

I am developing an open source wallet that handles multiple currencies and stores the keys in a deterministic key chain (BIP44).

It is currently on Android but it is written in am modular way so that the core library could be used in any java application. The library is based on a slightly modified Bitcoinj and for the blockchain queries it uses Electrum servers. It supports BTC, LTC, DOGE and in beta PPC, DRK, RDD and I am adding now NuBits.

Check out the repo from here: https://github.com/Coinomi/coinomi-android. At some point I will separate the core lib from the android app.

enjoy

Comment: @john-l-jegutanis great work you did there, by the way. we are all using your wallet!